# Apache kafka not pushing messages using NIFI

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I am trying to push message into my kafka topic using InvokeHttp but it shows a connection error.

Comment: Question has been answered already.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka does not accept HTTP connections. You need to use `PublishKafka` or `PublishKakfkaRecord`.